# Set x ticks for areas in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to do a special x-ticks labeling which I tried to illustrate in the photo below.
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Edit: A minimal version of my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xvalues = [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.]
yvalues = [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]

tx = [0] * len(xvalues)
for i in range(len(xvalues)):
    tx[i] = i

newxvalues = xvalues

seen = set()
newxvalues = [x if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else '' for x in newxvalues ]
newxvalues[0] = ' '
plt.plot(tx, yvalues, color='g', linewidth=1.5)
plt.xlim([-1, len(xvalues)])
plt.xticks(tx, newxvalues, rotation="90")
plt.ylim(-0.03, 1.1)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', top='off', bottom='off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit2: I don't need fancy brackets if that simplifies the problem. For example square brackets would also be okay

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. The following code provides a class `AxesDecorator` which you need to call at the end of your script. It needs an axes instance for which the ticklabeling should be changed, as well as the ticks that should be drawn. 
It assumes that all ticks are equally separated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

class AxesDecorator():
    def __init__(self, ax, size="5%", pad=0.05, ticks=[1,2,3], spacing=0.05,
                 color="k"):
        self.divider= make_axes_locatable(ax)
        self.ax = self.divider.new_vertical(size=size, pad=pad, sharex=ax, pack_start=True)
        ax.figure.add_axes(self.ax)
        self.ticks=np.array(ticks)
        self.d = np.mean(np.diff(ticks))
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.get_curve()
        self.color=color
        for x0 in ticks:
            self.plot_curve(x0)
        self.ax.set_yticks([])
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        self.ax.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both',length=0)
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both',length=0)
        for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
            self.ax.spines[direction].set_visible(False)
        self.ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel())
        ax.set_xlabel("")
        self.ax.set_xticks(self.ticks)

    def plot_curve(self, x0):
        x = np.linspace(x0-self.d/2.*(1-self.spacing),x0+self.d/2.*(1-self.spacing), 50 )
        self.ax.plot(x, self.curve, c=self.color)

    def get_curve(self):
        lx = np.linspace(-np.pi/2.+0.05, np.pi/2.-0.05, 25)
        tan = np.tan(lx)*10
        self.curve = np.hstack((tan[::-1],tan))
        return self.curve


# Do your normal plotting     
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [4,5,1,3,7]
ax.scatter(x,y, s=900, c=y, )
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ax.set_xlabel("Strange axis")

#at the end call the AxesDecorator class
# with the axes as argument
AxesDecorator(ax, ticks=x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This ansatz looks quite promising. Unfortunately the spacings are different. Would it help, if I post my code?

Comment: I don't need fancy brackets if that simplifies the problem. For example square brackets would also be okay.

Comment: This is just an example of how it can be done. Feel free to adapt the `AxesDecorator()` class to your needs.